# What is the hidden phrase in this story?

Tags: pattern, story

Could you find the hidden phrase in this fragment?

> "... What is that? A 3-complete word?" The
> puzzle-solver said. "Can it really be solved?"
> He thought as he tried different codes in
> the keyboard to open the door
>
> A voice in the dark answered: "Sure! it can
> be solved, just identify the pattern in the
> words"
>
> "You... you designed the pattern, don't you?"
> Our puzzle-solver replied. "no, it was already
> designed. Use your eyes to find the pattern",
> the voice said to him.
>
> Then, after deeply thinking, he said: "Yes!...
> it's solved!" Promptly, he opened the door
> using the code he found. "Excellent! the
> pattern was always in my hands", then he left
> the room, looking for the next puzzle to solve...

---

The answer to this puzzle serves as a hint for this one:
[What is a R-complete Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87459/what-is-an-r-complete-word)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's examine the short fragment of the story:

> "... **W**hat is that? **A** 3-complete word?" **T**he
>  puzzle-solver said. "**C**an it really be solved?"
>  **H**e thought as he tried different codes in
>  the keyboard to open the door
>
>  **A** voice in the dark answered: "**S**ure! it can
>  be solved, just identify the pattern in the
>  words"
>
>  "**Y**ou... you designed the pattern, don't you?"
>  **O**ur puzzle-solver replied. "no, it was already
>  designed. **U**se your eyes to find the pattern",
>  the voice said to him.
>
>  **T**hen, after deeply thinking, he said: "**Y**es!...
>  it's solved!" **P**romptly, he opened the door
>  using the code he found. "**E**xcellent! the
>  pattern was always in my hands", then he left
>  the room, looking for the next puzzle to solve...

Maybe you already saw the pattern.

> Extracting all uppercase letters from the text gives us the phrase
>  **WATCH AS YOU TYPE**

Additionally to the answer for this question, we now have another hint for solving [What is a R-complete Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87459/what-is-an-r-complete-word)

Comment: You are right...  I will leave it just in case someone wants to keep trying without checking all the hints.